# How to override routes in ng-admin?

Tags: angularjs, ng-admin

I want to change url in ng-admin state. For example, I need to add a trailing `/` at the URL for getting a list of users. (`http://localhost/api/v1/users/ instead` of `http://localhost/api/v1/users`)

Comment: Have a look here, it might be what you need https://github.com/marmelab/ng-admin/blob/master/doc/API-mapping.md

Answer (score 1):

The `Entity` and `View` classes offer a `baseUrl()` method, so it's probably not very hard. Just follow the directions from the documentation:

- https://github.com/marmelab/ng-admin/blob/master/doc/Configuration-reference.md#entity-configuration
- https://github.com/marmelab/ng-admin/blob/master/doc/Configuration-reference.md#entity-configuration
- https://github.com/marmelab/ng-admin/blob/master/doc/API-mapping.md